# Can't run "Where In" query in Kotlin

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, kotlin

I'm trying to make this kind of query (I'm working with postgres)to work:

```
 select * from users where user_id in [1,2,3]
```

the only problem is that the query can't work with this kind [1,2,3] of list
its working only with this kind (1,2,3).

I tried to convert the list [1,2,3] to the list (1,2,3)
but in Kotlin it didn't let me do it..

I would love for some help.

Comment: I'd imagine you will get more help if you post come code samples of what you tried that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension function to convert a list to string (1,2,3)

```
fun List<Int>.toParenthesis() = this.joinToString(separator = ",", prefix = "(", postfix = ")")
```

usage:

```
"select * from users where user_id in ${listOf(1,2,3).toParenthesis()}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If possible, it's preferred to work with prepared statements instead of dynamically generated SQL strings. The expression `con.createArrayOf("INTEGER", array)` should work in PostgreSQL:

```
val array = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)

/*
 * Or:
 * val data = listOf(1, 2, 3)
 * val array = data.toTypedArray()
 */

val con = getConnection()
val stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from users where user_id in ?")
stmt.setArray(1, con.createArrayOf("INTEGER", array))

val rs = stmt.executeQuery()
```